# Different posttypes for different authors

Tags: author, adsense

Now what I need to find a solution of is this issue:

I have 8 authors, and a bunch of posts. All authors have there own adsense (or other affiliate), we wish to show the adds belongings to the authors on there OWN posts.

So the author collects payment (if any) from there own posts, and only from there own posts.

Is there any way to make wordpress/theme do something like that?

Thanks
Marius

Comment: You have the information who the post author is, so having a post type per author shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Oh.. So what you are saying is that it IS possible for at post (from a guest view) to look "different" from author to author??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you have set up the different adsense.
I will assume that in your template there is a folder, called `'authors-ads'`, in it you have some php files, named after your **authors ids**, e.g.:

- `/authors-ads/author-1.php`
- `/authors-ads/author-12.php`

and so on.

after that in your `single.php` or whatever template you use to display posts

use

```
global $post;
get_template_part('authors-ads/author', $post->post_author );
```

in this way the file related to the post author is included in the page.

In that file put the ads related to the author, of course.

Comment: Yeah.. That sounds to be the easy way, I will try that out.

Thanks alot....

Answer (score 1):

Spawning multiple custom post types for authors is not their typical usage and would likely have too many unwanted implications.

It is pretty easy to retrieve info for the author of the post in template file (see [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_author_meta/) for example) and use it to conditionally output necessary individual data.